# Large number of zombie processes on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: 14.04, server, zombie

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 server and a few times in the last few days, MySQL has become unresponsive and I had to reboot remotely. I've been away until now so not able to have a proper look, but today I see thousands of the following zombies (# `ps -aef`):

```
sshd 1852 1 0 11:04 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
www-data 1888 1 0 11:05 ? 00:00:00 [spine] defunct
www-data 1941 1 0 09:02 ? 00:00:00 [spine] defunct
root 1946 1 0 11:05 ? 00:00:00 [pure-ftpd-mysql] defunct
sshd 1963 1 0 09:02 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 1975 1 0 06:46 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
root 1979 1 0 06:46 ? 00:00:00 [php5-fpm] defunct
mysql 1239 1 0 Apr21 ? 00:23:31 [mysqld] defunct
```

I restarted mysql and ran Zombie Slayer  http://blog.alexolivan.com/getting-r...bie-processes/ which uses gdb to kill all the zombie processes, but more are immediately appearing.

Within a couple of minutes I have:

```
root 18256 1 0 12:00 ? 00:00:00 [php5-fpm] defunct
sshd 18741 1 0 12:03 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 18746 1 0 12:03 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
root 18899 1 0 12:03 pts/3 00:00:00 [gdb] defunct
sshd 19038 1 0 12:03 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 19122 1 0 12:03 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 19124 1 0 12:03 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
www-data 19128 1 0 12:04 ? 00:00:00 [spine] defunct
sshd 19156 1 0 12:04 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 19236 1 0 12:04 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 19238 1 0 12:04 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
sshd 19337 1 0 12:04 ? 00:00:00 [sshd] defunct
```

...and the list is growing fairly rapidly (about 200 in half hour). I guess the problems occur when I run out of PIDs, but why is this happening? Can anyone suggest any lines of enquiry?

Comment: A "zombie" process happens when the parent process doesn't `wait` (see `man 2 wait`) for a subprocess and harvest the subprocess's exit status. What's starting these processes?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea - they are all orphans...